# CommandStateChange event won't fire in HTA iframe

Tags: events, webbrowser-control, jscript, hta

I have created an HTML-application to search through directories for a userdefined search term and return the results in a list. As part of this tool I gave the user the possibility to open the resulting folder directly inside an iframe in the application.

The tricky part now is to enable / disable the forward and backward-navigation buttons when the commandstate of the iframe changes.

I somehow can't add it to my iframe-element! Other events like BeforeNavigate2 otherwise work fine...

My code snippet:

```
<script>

var EmbededExplorer;
var EmbededExplorerObj;
var FSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");


function Body_OnLoad()
{

    InitEmbededExplorer();

}


function InitEmbededExplorer()
{
    var ExplorerDiv = document.getElementById("MyIFrameDiv");
    EmbededExplorer = document.createElement("IFRAME");
    EmbededExplorer.setAttribute("type", "text/html");

    EmbededExplorer.setAttribute("style", "float:left;width:90%;height:100%;border:0px");
    ExplorerDiv.insertBefore(EmbededExplorer, ExplorerDiv.children(2));
    EmbededExplorer.setAttribute("src", "C:\");

    EmbededExplorerNavigateTo("C:\SomeDirectory\HighlightedFile.txt");
}

function EmbededExplorerNavigateTo(Destination)
{
    var E = null;
    var Path;
    Path = FSO.GetParentFolderName(Destination);

    if (FSO.FolderExists(Destination))
    {
        Path = Destination;
    }
    else if (FSO.FileExists(Destination))
    {
        Path = FSO.GetParentFolderName(Destination);
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Unable to locate the file or directory.");
    }

    try
    {
        EmbededExplorer.setAttribute("src", Path);

    }
    catch (Excep)
    {
        E = Excep;
    }

    if (E != null)
    {
        alert("Could not open directory. Please refer to the administrator.");
    }
    else
    {
        //UpdateFolderAddressBar(document.getElementById('MyIFrameAddressBar'), Path);
        setTimeout(function() { RegisterEmbededBrowserAfterLoading(Destination); }, 100);
    }
}

function RegisterEmbededBrowserAfterLoading(SelectItem)
{
    if (EmbededExplorer.contentWindow.document.readyState == "loading")
    {
        setTimeout(function() { RegisterEmbededBrowserAfterLoading(SelectItem); }, 100);
    }
    else
    {
        //EmbededExplorer.contentWindow.document.childNodes[0] contains the actual (shell-)explorer-component of the iframe (a WebBrowser2 class component)
        EmbededExplorer.contentWindow.document.childNodes[0].RegisterAsBrowser = true;
        EmbededExplorerObj = EmbededExplorer.contentWindow.document.childNodes[0];

        //All my attempts to add the CommandStateChange-Event
        EmbededExplorer.attachEvent("CommandStateChange", EmbededExplorerObj_CommandStateChange);
        EmbededExplorerObj.attachEvent("CommandStateChange", EmbededExplorerObj_CommandStateChange);
        EmbededExplorer.CommandStateChange = function(a, b) {alert("CommandStateChange fired!!");};
        EmbededExplorerObj.CommandStateChange = function(a, b) {alert("CommandStateChange fired!!");};

        //The following event works fine...
        EmbededExplorerObj.attachEvent("BeforeNavigate2", EmbededExplorerObj_BeforeNavigate2);
        if (SelectItem)
        {
            EmbededExplorerObj.Document.SelectItem(SelectItem.replace(/\//g, "\\"), 16 + 8 + 1);
        }
    }
}

function EmbededExplorerObj_CommandStateChange(Command, Enable)
{
    alert("CommandStateChange fired!!");
    //Code to enable / disable my forward / backward navigation buttons
}

function EmbededExplorerObj_BeforeNavigate2(Obj, URL)
{
    alert("BeforeNavigate2 fired!!");
    //UpdateFolderAddressBar(document.getElementById('MyIFrameAddressBar'), URL);
}
</script>
```

Documentation of the required event: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa768328%28v%3dvs.85%29

For validation purpose, I rebuilt the event in VBA and it works just fine.

```
Private WithEvents Win As WebBrowser

Sub SetWin()
    Dim WinShell 'As New Shell32.Shell
    Set WinShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set Win = WinShell.Windows(1)
End Sub

Private Sub Win_CommandStateChange(ByVal Command As Long, ByVal Enable As Boolean)
    Stop 'fires 3x after every navigation, each time containing my desired state-information in the 'Command' parameter
End Sub
```

EDIT:
As requested I will add the structure of my application below:

```
    <BODY Onload="Initialisieren()" OnContextMenu="return false;" OnClick="VerbergeContextMenus()" OnKeyPress="Body_OnKeyPress()" OnFocus="document.getElementById('ModNr').focus()" OnBeforeUnload="TempLeeren();">
        <TABLE Style="Width: 100%; Height: 100vh" border="0">
            <TR Style="Height:auto">
                <TD Style="Width: 50%; Vertical-Align: text-top">
                    <LABEL For="ModNr" Class="Überschrift" OnSelectStart="return false;">Suchbegriff:</LABEL><INPUT ID="ModNr" Type="Text" UseContextMenuId="CopyPasteContextMenu" onContextMenu="ZeigeContextMenu(this, event);return false;">
                </TD>
                <TD Style="Width: 50%; Vertical-Align: text-top">
                    <DIV Class="Überschrift" OnSelectStart="return false;">Zuletzt geöffnet:</DIV>
                </TD>
            </TR>
            <TR Style="Height:auto">
                <TD>
                    <DIV Class="Bereich" ID="Auswahl" OnSelectStart="return false;">
                        <TABLE Style="Width: 100%" ID="AuswahlTabelle">
                            <TR></TR>
                            <TR Style="Height: 30px">
                                <TD ColSpan="99" Style="Vertical-Align: Bottom"><INPUT ID="SuchKnopf" Type="Button" Value="Suche"></TD>
                            </TR>
                        </TABLE>
                    </DIV>
                    <DIV Class="Bereich" ID="DatenBankAuswahl" OnSelectStart="return false;">
                        <TABLE Style="Width: 100%; Margin: 0px; Padding: 0px" ID="DatenBankAuswahlTabelle">
                            <TR></TR>
                        </TABLE>
                    </DIV>
                </TD>
                <TD Style="Vertical-Align: Top" rowSpan="99">
                    <DIV Class="ListenBereich" Name="Historie" ID="Historie" Type="Radio" size="20" OnSelectStart="return false;">
                    </DIV>
                </TD>
            </TR>
            <TR Style="Height:auto">
                <TD>
                    <DIV Class="Überschrift" OnSelectStart="return false;" Id="Überschrift">Suchergebnisse:</DIV>
                </TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD>
                    <DIV Class="ListenBereich" Name="Ergebnisse" ID="Ergebnisse" OnSelectStart="return false;">
                    </DIV>
                    <DIV Class="Bereich" Name="MyIFrameDiv" ID="MyIFrameDiv" style="display:none">
                        <BUTTON ID="ExplorerCloseBtn" Title="Schließen" Style="float:right;min-width:1px;width:5%;height:100%;border-radius:0px 8px 8px 0px;margin:0px;padding:0px" OnClick="SuchergebnisseAnzeigen();"><div style="position:relative;font-family:'wingdings 2';font-Size:20px">T</DIV></BUTTON>
                        <DIV Style="float:left;min-width:1px;width:5%;height:100%;margin:0px;padding:0px">
                            <BUTTON disabled="true" ID="ExplorerNavigateRootBtn" Title="Zum übergeordneten Verzeichnis" Style="float:left;min-width:1px;width:100%;height:33%;border-radius:8px 0px 0px 0px;margin:0px;padding:0px" OnClick="ExplorerNavToRoot();"><div style="position:relative;font-family:'wingdings 3';font-Size:20px">Í</DIV></BUTTON>
                            <BUTTON disabled="false" ID="ExplorerNavigateGoBack" Title="Einen Schritt zurück" Style="float:left;min-width:1px;width:100%;height:34%;border-radius:0px 0px 0px 0px;margin:0px;padding:0px" OnClick="try{ EmbededExplorerObj.goBack(); } catch(Excep) { }"><div style="position:relative;font-family:'wingdings 3';font-Size:20px">§</DIV></BUTTON>
                            <BUTTON disabled="false" ID="ExplorerNavigateGoForward" Title="Einen Schritt vor" Style="float:left;min-width:1px;width:100%;height:33%;border-radius:0px 0px 0px 8px;margin:0px;padding:0px" OnClick="try{ EmbededExplorerObj.goForward(); } catch(Excep) { }"><div style="position:relative;font-family:'wingdings 3';font-Size:20px">¨</DIV></BUTTON>
                        </DIV>
                    </DIV>
                </TD>
            </TR>
        </TABLE>
    </BODY>
```

Comment: Referencing the `IFRAME` in the DOM is not the same as a `window`. The example in VBA is not equivalent.

Comment: Please see the comments in my code snippet. You can get access to the actual Window-Component by using <WebbrowserObject> = <IFRAME-Element>.contentWindow.document.childNodes[0];.

Comment: Wouldn’t the `window` be equivalent to `<IFRAME-element>.contentWindow`? Seems to me your trying to capture the event from the wrong object. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow)

Comment: Ideally would help to see the structure of the HTA file, without it it’s hard to quantify how the script fits into it.

Comment: @Lankymart I can't attach an event to <IFRAME-element>.contentWindow. My code will crash with an "Invalid calling object" exception. I also added the structue of my HTA in the initial post.